# Unique email lookup methodology

Tags: mysql, database, scalability

**Solution!**
I did what @pilcrow suggested. Looked for mysql_error_num:1062 (unique email) and returned an error if so.

**Description:**

I am building an application that requires many different users and possibly companies to sign up via registration forms. I want to make sure that the email entered by the individual is unique as a company might give out a generic `info@company.com` email to many users.

I want to be able to check against the database to see if email exists.

**Problem:**

I already know how to accomplish this via `Javascript`, `ajax` and `PHP` but I am afraid that if I have many (thousands) of users, the query is going to take forever. Especially if I decide to use a `keypress` event instead of a `blur` event on the form. I might be wrong, but I can't see a simple `WHERE email = $email` is very scalable.

**Question**

Is there a way I can set up my code or the database (mysql) to speed up the query? I was thinking of setting up a separate table just for emails, but don't think that would work.

Thank you!

**p.s.** I am pretty set on database/server technology so `PHP`+`MYSQL` it is.

Comment: Set a timeout on keydown to only run the ajax request if the user hasn't typed anything for x seconds.

Comment: that is a good idea, but even that could get slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask

> *Is there a way I can set up my code or the database (mysql) to speed up the query?*

Yes, omit the query entirely.

Put a UNIQUE constraint on the email address as stored in your backend database, and then be prepared to catch [ER_DUP_UNIQUE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_unique) when INSERTion of a new account fails because of a duplicate email address.

That approach prevents duplicates and warns the new user when a duplicate has been chosen.

I very much doubt that you need to look up email addresses as they are being typed (*"...if I decide to use a `keypress` event..."*).  If you really do want to check that the address exists before INSERTing, you'll also need a transaction to prevent [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) hilarity.  However, since the UNIQUE constraint is your simplest but most effective defense against duplicates, just implement that.

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. The issue is, I'm using CodeIgniter and might not be able to select specific issues. I'll look into it and update the question accordingly, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague about what you would be storing in the database.  What is the downside to a separate table for emails?

What you really need, more than a table, is an index on email.  The underlying table could be emails only or it could have additional user information.  However, if you execute a query such as:

```
 select email
 from t
 where email = <your email to check>
 limit 1
```

Then the query will use the index efficiently to do the matching.

Comment: I didn't mean that there is a downside, but I just thought it was unnecessary, would implementing an email-only table make sense? As far as the `indexing`, could you maybe elaborate a little bit on that? I am going to google it now

Comment: @phil . . . Indexes are a data structure that databases use to make queries run faster.  In this case, they will greatly speed the time it takes to find a duplicate email.  The topic is quite extensive.  Google and Wikipedia have ltos of information on the subject, as does database documentation.